# CPP: why is dereferencing a pointer to a template type not populating a variable?

Tags: c++

I do a lot of modeling and simulation and I am writing a sim_logger in CPP. The basics of it are this: a user constructs the class with a logging frequency and an output path. They can then "register" any number of variables which gives the logger a reference to the desired variable (its not incredibly safe right now but I'll work on that later, focused on the issue at hand). I've created a template type called "variable" which contains three things, T *var, T last_val, and string ID. My problem is this, whenever I set the last_val equivalent to the var, the last_val inside the variable does not actually change. I am setting this value in line 180 of sim_logger.h. I feel like this is a silly problem, probably due to some misunderstanding I have of pointers. However, I've tried several different things and cannot seem to solve this problem.

---

sim_logger.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <math.h>

pragma once

// a class to log simulation data
// specifically for logging time dependent differential functions
class sim_logger
{
private:

    // a type that represents a variable
    /*
    meant to contain anything, but limited by the variadic type
    "poly_var_types" below
    */
    template <typename T>
    struct variable
    {
        T           *var; // pointer to the variable itself
        T           last_val; // the last value of the variable
        std::string ident; // the identity of the variable
    };
    
    // a variadic type
    template <typename ... T>
    using poly_var_types = std::variant<T...>;
    
    // defined variable types
    // these are the typical types that are logged, feel free to add more
    using var_types = poly_var_types<
        variable<double>,
        variable<float>
        // variable<int>,
        // variable<bool>,
        // variable<std::string>
    >;
    
    // class members
    std::vector<var_types> registered_variables; // container of all variables
    std::ofstream          file; // output file stream
    double                 dt; // the logging time step in seconds
    double                 clock = 0.0; // the logging clock in seconds
    double                 last_sim_time = clock; // the last sim time for interp
    bool                   is_time_to_log = false; // flag for log function
    const double           EPSILON = 0.000000001; // rounding error
    
    // a linear interpolation method
    // only returns floating point values
    double lin_interp(double x, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
    {
        return (y1+(x-x1)*((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)));
    }

public:

    // constructor which sets the logging frequency and output path
    // log_dt is a floating point value in units of seconds
    // path_to_file is a string representation of the desired output path
    sim_logger(double log_dt, std::string path_to_file)
    {
        dt = log_dt;
        file.open(path_to_file);
        file << std::setprecision(16) << std::fixed;
    }
    
    // method to register a variable with the logger
    template <typename T>
    void register_variable(std::string ident, T *aVar)
    {
        variable<T> v;
        v.ident = ident;
        v.var = aVar;
        registered_variables.push_back(v);
    };
    
    // a method to write the log file header and log sim time 0.0 data
    void write_header_and_log_init_data()
    {
        // write header
        file << "sim_time" << " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < registered_variables.size(); i++)
        {
            std::visit([&](auto rv)
            {
                if (i == registered_variables.size()-1)
                    file << rv.ident << "\n";
                else
                    file << rv.ident << " ";
            }, registered_variables[i]);
        }
    
        // log all registered variables
        file << clock << " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < registered_variables.size(); i++)
        {
            std::visit([&](auto rv)
            {
                if (i == registered_variables.size()-1)
                    file << *rv.var << "\n";
                else
                    file << *rv.var << " ";
            }, registered_variables[i]);
        }
    }
    
    // method to log all registered variables
    void log_data(double sim_time)
    {
        // check the timing
        if (sim_time > (clock + dt))
        {
            is_time_to_log = true;
        }
    
        // check if its time to log
        if (is_time_to_log)
        {
            // update the clock
            clock += dt;
    
            // debug
            std::cout << "\n";
    
            // log all registered variables
            file << clock << " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < registered_variables.size(); i++)
            {
                std::visit([&](auto rv)
                {
    
                    // instantiate the value to be logged
                    double log_val;
    
                    // debug
                    std::cout << rv.last_val << " " << *rv.var << std::endl;
    
                    // if sim time is even with clock time, log at time
                    if (fabs(sim_time - clock) < EPSILON)
                    // if (true)
                    {
                        log_val = *rv.var;
                    }
                    // if sim time is past clock time, interpolate
                    else
                    {
                        log_val = lin_interp(sim_time, last_sim_time,
                            clock, rv.last_val, *rv.var);
                    }
    
                    // if last variable in vector create new line
                    if (i == registered_variables.size()-1)
                        file << log_val << "\n";
                    // otherwise just whitespace
                    else 
                        file << log_val << " ";
                }, registered_variables[i]);
            }
    
            // debug
            std::cout << "\n";
    
            // reset flag
            is_time_to_log = false;
        }
    
        // get all the last values
        for (int i = 0; i < registered_variables.size(); i++)
        {
            std::visit([&](auto rv)
            {
                // have to get last value at every update call
                // This works in scope but the memory does not actually change?
                // I am very confuse.
                rv.last_val = *rv.var;
    
                // debug
                std::cout << rv.last_val << " " << *rv.var << std::endl;
            }, registered_variables[i]);
        }
    
        // set the last sim time
        last_sim_time = sim_time;
    }

};
```

---

---

main.cpp

```
include <iostream>
include "sim_logger.h"

int main()
{
sim_logger logger(0.1, "sim_logger/log.dat");

    double test1 = 100.0;
    double test2 = 100.0;
    double test3 = 100.0;
    
    logger.register_variable("test1", &test1);
    logger.register_variable("test2", &test2);
    logger.register_variable("test3", &test3);
    
    logger.write_header_and_log_init_data();
    
    double simTime = 0.0;
    double simDt   = 1.0 / 20.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        simTime += simDt;
        test1 += 1.0;
        test2 += 2.0;
        test3 += 3.0;
        logger.log_data(simTime);
    }
    
    return 0;

};
```

---

---

output

```
101 101
102 102
103 103
102 102
104 104
106 106

1.88705e-26 103
1.88705e-26 106
1.88705e-26 109

103 103
106 106
109 109
```

---

Comment: `auto rv`: Your visitor takes the argument by-value. You are modifying the local function parameter object which is a copy of the passed object. It seems you intended to take a reference `auto& rv` instead. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::visit([&](auto rv)
```

`rv` is, effectively, a parameter to this function (the closure, for the purposes of this answer, is effectively a function).

As you know: in C++ function parameters get passed by value. For example, using a simple function:

```
void func(int x)
{
    x=5;
}
```

This `func` can set `x` to `5` as often as it wants. Whatever actually gets passed in, by anyone that calls `func()`, will remain unaffected:

```
int z=7;

func(z);
```

`z` is still 7. Even though `func` set its parameter to 5. This is fundamental to C++:

```
            std::visit([&](auto rv)
            {
                rv.last_val = *rv.var;
```

So, this sets `rv.last_val`. Great. But this has no effect on whatever gets passed into here.

```
            }, registered_variables[i]);
```

The visited instance of this variant is still what it is. It hasn't changed. Why would it change? C++ does not work this way.

So, if your intent, here, is to modify `registered_variables[i]`, it should be ***passed by reference***:

```
std::visit([&](auto &rv)
```

Now, the object ***referenced*** by `rv` gets modified.

Comment: You are the man. I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you much.